# How to download image from url?

Tags: ruby, net-http

I have an url:
http://limg.imgsmail.ru/splash/v/i/icons.v16.14afed9dda24aad97c9dc5bf24396fbd6ede4e22.png
and if I try to get this png file with 'net/http'

```
Net::HTTP.start('www.limg.imgsmail.ru') {|http|
        rest = http.get('/splash/v/i/icons.v16.14afed9dda24aad97c9dc5bf24396fbd6ede4e22.png')
        open('1.png', 'wb') {|file| file.write(rest.body)}
    }
```

I have an error: SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known.
Why is this happening? The full link is correct!
How can I download such files?

Comment: I'm not able to access 'www.limg.imgsmail.ru'; perhaps the issue isn't in your ruby syntax but in your connection to this site?

Comment: I'm not able too, but the whole link is "alive". May be there is another method to download this image?

Comment: What is that supposed to mean? The link is "alive" but no one can access it? Most people would say that means the link is dead.

Comment: I mean that the full path to the source (image) is correct. If You try to click on link above, You'll see the source I want to get.

Comment: Remove the `www.` from your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
require "open-uri"

File.open('1.png', 'wb') do |fo|
  fo.write open("http://limg.imgsmail.ru/splash/v/i/icons.v16.14afed9dda24aad97c9dc5bf24396fbd6ede4e22.png").read 
end
```

**Note:** I have removed `www` from your url as with that url is not working. **[this url](http://limg.imgsmail.ru/splash/v/i/icons.v16.14afed9dda24aad97c9dc5bf24396fbd6ede4e22.png)** works fine.

Comment: @andgursky : glad to help. You can accept and upvote my answer